# Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Object' while attempting to activate 'MediatR.ServiceFactory'

Tags: asp.net-core, startup, asp.net-core-3.0, mediatr

I have an Asp.net Core 2.2 app that I'm trying to upgrade to 3.0. I'm using Mediatr and now I got this error after upgrading to 3.0

> Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: System.ICloneable Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: MediatR.ServiceFactory': Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Object' while attempting to activate 'MediatR.ServiceFactory'.

Here is my code in the Startup.cs

```
services.AddMediatR(typeof(BlogPost));
```

and I'm using Scrutor to scan `IMediator`

```
services.Scan(scan => scan
          .FromAssembliesOf(typeof(ISettingService), typeof(IMediator), typeof(BlogPost), typeof(IHomeHelper))
          .AddClasses()
          .UsingRegistrationStrategy(RegistrationStrategy.Skip) 
          .AsImplementedInterfaces()
          .WithScopedLifetime());
```

The above code works in 2.2, but now I cannot get the program to even launch due to the error.  Could someone shed some light on what is going wrong please?

Answer (score 1):

Disable validate scope.

```
// Program.cs
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
 WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
 .UseStartup<Startup>()
 .UseDefaultServiceProvider(options => options.ValidateScopes = false) // <<<<<<<<<<<
 .Build();
```

Comment: I tried it and it worked, but I'm still not totally understanding what is happening even though I did google it and read on this topic. I thought the validate scopes is to protect you from having scoped services injected to singletons from the root provider, so by turning the ValidateScopes off, will there be side effects? Thank you.